# How long do the Flesh Tearers have?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In the latest novel about the Space Wolves called Ragnar Blackmane it is cited that the Flesh Tearers have 100 (?) years to live as a chapter.

However in the [Lexicanum](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Flesh_Tearers) it is stated that they will die off in the next 2 millennia if a cure for the Black Rage isn't found. Which is it? Or is this just another oopsie in the W40K continuum?
It would be interesting to find out what Mr. Dembski has to say about it.

I will settle for a correct answer about how long the chapter has to "live".

Comment: Since the info in Lexicanum is usually more official (and since Ragnar is not really a prophet/scientist etc) I'd go with the 2 millennia answer. Unless he meant i.e. that they have about 100 years to live as a loyal chapter until the Black Rage will turn them into insane berserkers

Comment: @Yasskier Ragnar didn't say it. The Castellan of the Flesh Tearers did say it himself.

Comment: I am sure that they are all projections. Both and none are right. The line in Lexicanum does not even have a citation for it to reference... All the same it is just another example of misinformation in the 40k universe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has changed since you posted this question, going from "Probably Hours" during the last stand of the Blood Angels and their successor chapters on Baal fighting the Tyranids to now essentially an indeterminate period of time as long as they can continue to get new Primaris marines as reinforcements, especially as these appear to be immune to the Black Rage.

Comment: I dont understand your answer... can you please fix it up. I am asking about Fleash tearers, not Blood Angels and what are the Primaris marines?  Also where is this information coming from? a site? a book?

Comment: @Cherubel The Flesh Tearers are a Blood Angels successor chapter, and thus were at Baal alongside the parent chapter defending against a Tyranid invasion. Primaris Marines are a new "generation" of Marines that were developed after the events of the "Gathering Storm" books. All of this comes from the latest Blood Angels codex.